# PHP: Setting missing " in HTML-code with preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

I've got a database with a lot of user made entries grown about 10 years. The users had the option to put HTML-code in their content. And some didn't that well. So I've a lot of  content in where the quotes are missing. Need a valid HTML-code for an ex/import via XML.

Had tested to replace  width  but my regex doesn't work. Do you've an idea where's my fault?

```
$out=preg_replace("/<a href=h(.)*>/","<a href=\"h$1\">",$out);
```

PS: If you have an idea how to automatically make a correction on wrong html source this would alternatively be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to use `"/<a href=h(.*)>/"` (mind the star *inside* the parenthesis) since you want to capture all characters after the `h` and before the `>` inside the capture group.

You can also use `<a href=([^"].*)>` since the href may not start with `h`. This regex captures all `href` values that do not start with `"`.

Yet, all of these assume that the `href` is the last attribute in your `a`, i.e.., ending with `>`.

As a more general rule, I came up with `(?<key>\w*)\s*=\s*(?<value>[^"][^\s>]*)` that finds attribute-value pairs, separated by `=`. The values may not start with `"`, and they go until the next whitespace or `>`. Use this with caution, since it may fail in serveral circumstances: Multi-line html, inline JavaScript, etc.

Whether it is a good idea to use RegEx for such a task is a different discussion.